# Alternatives to Local Storage with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, local-storage

I'm working on an app that needs to post frequently to the server using ajax, which slows down performance. As a workaround, I started testing localStorage as an alternative. The results are less than ideal, retrieving/setting localStorage frequently is super slow (something I was surprised to find), and kills performance.

On the other-hand, I don't really want to post to the server every time an event is fired, as this has pretty much the same performance as localStorage.

I'm wondering what other solutions there are?

Could I create a "data" object that gets continually updated when events are fired? With a timeout function that falls-back to post? If so how would you set that up?

What options are there for storing data on events that can be retrieved quickly? If someone could point me in the right direction I'd be super appreciative.

Comment: Just how frequently are you saving stuff? I've never had slowdown when using `localStorage`...

Comment: You should describe what you're trying to do, otherwise you're just asking us to "recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource", which is off-topic

Comment: when events are fired (which depends on the user) but probably max 2 per second.

Comment: Why do you need to save something 2 time per second. Is that data really so important?

Comment: Can you use an object with JSON to store on the fly?

Comment: Sounds like if writing to localstorage is slow, the problem would be converting that data to the string.

Answer (score 0):

simple solution is to collect the information you wish to save in an array and save it once in a while

```
buffer = [];

// collect all mousemove events on #mydiv
$('#mydiv').mousemove(function(event) {
    buffer.push(event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY)
})

createInterval(function() {
   if (buffer.length > 0) { // save only if something happened
       var to_transmit = buffer;  // theoretically between this line and the next 
                // line you may miss an event, but in practice I wouldn't worry
       buffer = [];  // new buffer - next events will be inserted here
       $.ajax({url: "/post/here/", data: to_transmit})
   }
},
5000); // send ajax every 5 seconds
```